# How to edit string from STDOUT

Tags: python, subprocess, netsh

I have this code:

```
netshcmd = subprocess.Popen('netsh wlan stop hostednetwork', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = netshcmd.communicate()
if errors:
    print("Warrning: ", errors)
else:
    print("Success", output)
```

and output is this:

```
Success b'The hosted network stopped. \r\n\r\n'
```

How to get output like this "Success The hosted network stopped."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from a sub-process gives you a *bytestring*. You could either decode this bytestring (you'll have to find a suitable encoding), or use the `universal_newlines` option and have Python automatically decode it for you:

```
netshcmd = subprocess.Popen(
    'netsh wlan stop hostednetwork', 
    shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True)
```

From the [*Frequently Used Arguments* documentation section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If *universal_newlines* is `True`, these file objects will be opened as text streams in universal newlines mode using the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`. For `stdin`, line ending characters `'\n'` in the input will be converted to the default line separator `os.linesep`. For `stdout` and `stderr`, all line endings in the output will be converted to `'\n'`. For more information see the documentation of the `io.TextIOWrapper` class when the newline argument to its constructor is `None`.

For a process run via the shell, `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` should be *exactly* the right codec to use, as that gets the information on what encoding to use from the exact same location that other processes like `netsh` are supposed to consult, the [locale environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html).

With `universal_newlines=True`, `output` will be set to the string `'The hosted network stopped. \n\n'; note the newlines at the end. You may want to use`str.strip()` to remove the extra whitespace there:

```
print("Success", output.strip())
```

Comment: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is equivalent to ANSI code page on Windows such as cp1252 but the stdout encoding may be OEM codepage such as cp437 in `cmd.exe` (run by `shell=True` on Windows). I don't know what character encoding `netsh` uses here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: hrmz, so netsh is a Windows command, I missed that. I can't find any info on what output it produces and how localised the messages are. :-/

Answer (score 0):

That is a bytestring. Change your code to make that a str:

```
netshcmd = subprocess.Popen('netsh wlan stop hostednetwork', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = netshcmd.communicate()
if errors:
    print("Warrning: ", errors.decode())
else:
    print("Success", output.decode())
```

Comment: Don't make the assumption that UTF-8 is always correct. Explicitly specify a codec; for external processes run via the shell the return value of `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` would be a good guess.

Comment: Thank you, Bishakh.